# Need help in writing a cloud function for sending notification to particular users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have my firestore structure like this:

Restaurant //Collection (C)

- RestID // Document (D)

  - Orders // C

    - OrderID

      - document with order details
  - riders - an array of phone numbers (D)

Riders (C)

- riderID

  - document with rider details and Firebase token

The app first creates a profile of the rider and then listen to the respective RestID and orders created inside it. This part works fine.

I have implemented FCM in the app and it receives the FCM notification when sent from the console. This part works fine.

I need some help in writing a cloud function to automate this notification process. This process will help create notification when the app is not in foreground. I do not know typescript or Javascript in much detail but trying to learn and write some code to automate this notification sending part and have written the following (apologies as it's a mix of pseudocode and actual code)

```
export const triggerFunc = functions.firestore
.document('Restaurant/{restID}/Orders/{orderID}')
.onCreate((snap,context)=>{
    const restaurantDocument = admin.firestore().doc('{restID}').get()
    //Pseudocode from here onwards
    if (Riders.{profile}.phonevalue exists in restaurantDocument.riderArrayPhoneValue){
        sendNotification(Riders.profile.fireBaseInstanceIDField)
    }

})

function sendNotification(fireBaseInstanceID:String){
    // send notifictaion to fireBaseInstanceID
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using phone numbers instead of `userId` in the `riders` array within the order document, I mean you could just use the `userId` to fin the right registration token, no?

Comment: Writing a function you could use, I think it would be better if you put an array of tokens registration in the `RestID` document, is that possible?

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Answer (score 1):

This `cloud-function` should help you getting started, more info in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

```
firestore = admin.firestore();
exports.notifyRider = functions
    .firestore.document('Restaurant/{restID}/Orders/{orderID}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const orderData = snapshot.data();
        const restID = context.params.restID;
        return firestore.doc(`Restaurant/${restID}`).get()
            .then(restaurantData => {
                // Here I'm assuming riders is an array of registration tokens
                // otherwise you will have to query your riders collection to get access to the registration tokens
                const riders = restaurantData.data().riders;
                // By using multicast you simply set your registration tokens array in the payload
                return admin.messaging().sendMulticast({
                    // I personally prefer to use only data messages to have more customization
                    // if your app is closed or in the foreground you will get the same message
                        data: {
                        date: context.timestamp,
                        title: orderData.order_something,
                        message: orderData.order_something_else,
                        something_else: something_else
                        restaurant: restID,
                        // etc, etc
                    },
                    tokens: riders
                });
            })
            .catch(reason => {
                console.warn(`Rejection Code: ${reason.code}`);
                console.warn(`Rejection Message: ${reason.message}`);
            });
    });
```